# How to ORDER BY which ever Parameter comes first in the URL or MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, url, mysqli, parameters

When I run the query, it keeps grouping tags in a random order.

This is how it looks currently:

https://www.example.com/app/user-images.php?tags=peace&tags2=dogs&tags3=aesthetic

Image #1 - peace

Image #2 - peace

Image #3 - dogs

Image #4 - dogs

Image #5 - aesthetic

Image #6 - peace

Expected Result:

Image #1 - peace

Image #2 - peace

Image #3 - peace

Image #4 - dogs

Image #5 - dogs

Image #6 - aesthetic

Is there a way I can possibly do this? First tag would be peace, second dogs, third aesthetic based on the URL. Here is my code:

```
$tags = $_GET['tags'];
$tags2 = $_GET['tags2'];
$tags3 = $_GET['tags3'];

$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN user_images ON users.username = user_images.username WHERE tags = '$tags' OR tags = '$tags2' OR tags = '$tags3' ORDER BY user_images.tags ASC");
```

I tried using `ORDER BY user_images.tags ASC` but that doesn't really help since no matter where I put the tags in the URL, they all come the same order.

Comment: `order by tags = '$tags', tags = '$tags2', tags = '$tags3'`

Comment: @Moob Thank you, this almost work but for some reason it's going backwards. The third tag is going first and the first is going third.

Comment: Sort descending. Eg: `order by tags = '$tags' desc, tags = '$tags2' desc, tags = '$tags3' desc`

Comment: @Moob Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @Moob : this is a nice solution, I believe that you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Laney You're welcome.

Comment: @GMB You're right. I've posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by multiple criteria, so in this case adding your search terms to the ordering should work. E.G:

```
...
ORDER BY tags = '$tags' DESC, tags = '$tags2' DESC, tags = '$tags3' DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

The first idea that comes to mind is to do 3 separate queries, one for each tag:

```php
$results = [];
foreach ([$tags, $tags2, $tags3] as $tag) {
    $fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN user_images ON users.username = user_images.username WHERE tags = '$tag'");
    while ($row = $fetch->fetch_assoc())
        $results[] = $row;
    $fetch->close();
}
```

While this code probably works, it leaves a wide open door for **SQL injection**. You should use positional parameters inside the query and pass the actual values outside of the query to prevent that.

Comment: much apperciated, but I got this error in the code: `Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`. I've never seen `array_merge`, it seems interesting.

Comment: @radu a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) would work here.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams You are right, mysqli_query() returns an object, so you have to extract the results before you can merge them. I have edited my answer and replaced the code with something that actually works. I apologize for not checking it in the first place.

Comment: @Moob I totally agree a "UNION" works too. Performance is always debatable, but sometimes multiple simple queries are faster than a single more complex query. In this case, all results need to be fetched into PHP eventually. On the other hand, if a limit/offset is needed on the result, then the UNION is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression to control your ordering, giving priority to each tag in order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
JOIN user_images ON users.username = user_images.username 
WHERE tags = '$tags' OR tags = '$tags2' OR tags = '$tags3' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN tags = '$tags' THEN 1
              WHEN tags = '$tags2' THEN 2
              WHEN tags = '$tags3' THEN 3
              END
```